# Racket: How do I make the -s option to "raco test" work?

Tags: racket

According to the [docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/raco/test.html) for `raco test`, there is a `-s` option that will test submodules with names other than `test`.  But I can't seem to make this work.  If I have the following file:

```
;; example.rkt

#lang racket

(module foo racket
  (display "Hi, I'm running!"))
```

Then trying to pass `foo` as the submodule name to `raco test` results in:

```
$ raco test example.rkt -s foo
testing example.rkt
test: Given path #<path:-s> does not exist
  context...:
   /Applications/Racket v5.3.3/collects/compiler/commands/test.rkt: [running body]
   /Applications/Racket v5.3.3/collects/raco/raco.rkt: [running body]
   /Applications/Racket v5.3.3/collects/raco/main.rkt: [running body]
```

If I just use the name `test`:

```
;; example.rkt

#lang racket

(module test racket
  (display "Hi, I'm running!"))
```

Then, `raco test` works fine:

```
$ raco test example.rkt
testing example.rkt
Hi, I'm running!
```

But I really want to have several test suites that I selectively run with various calls to `raco test`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try passing the flag before the filename. Like this:

```
$ raco test -s foo example.rkt
```

Comment: Pfft.  Yes, that was it.  Thanks, Asumu.